# Efficient way to create column referencing its own previous value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a few columns in a dataframe with datetime index based on a rule which references their own previous values. I have tried a for loop on the length of df as per below but looking for a cleaner solution if possible?

Because what I want to do in the end is get the stats of generated columns (C,D,E in below example) over a large number of A,B....

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 2), columns=list('AB'))
reset_level = 0.5
df['diff'] = df['A'].diff()
df['C'], df['D'], df['E'] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if abs(df.iloc[i-1]['C'] + df.iloc[i]['diff']) > (reset_level):
        df.iat[i,3] = 0.000
        df.iat[i,4] = (df.iloc[i-1]['C'] + df.iloc[i]['diff'])
    else:
        df.iat[i,3] = (df.iloc[i-1]['C'] + df.iloc[i]['diff'])
        df.iat[i,4] = 0.000 
    df.iat[i,5] = 0.5 * df.iloc[i]['D'] * df.iloc[i]['D']
```

Edit : Adding expected output below

```
         A        B         diff        C             D                 E
0   -0.352725   1.429037    NaN         0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
1   -1.024418   -0.644302   -0.671693   0.000000    -0.671693   0.225585
2   0.401065    0.419555    1.425483    0.000000    1.425483    1.016001
3   -1.302484   0.724320    -1.703549   0.000000    -1.703549   1.451039
4   0.427035    0.835221    1.729518    0.000000    1.729518    1.495617
5   0.158694    -0.416741   -0.268340   -0.268340   0.000000    0.000000
6   0.921985    -0.490635   0.763291    0.494951    0.000000    0.000000
7   -0.835297   -1.036580   -1.757282   0.000000    -1.262331   0.796740
8   0.752060    -0.279206   1.587356    0.000000    1.587356    1.259850
9   1.795306    -1.554886   1.043246    0.000000    1.043246    0.544181
10  -0.405100   -0.361454   -2.200406   0.000000    -2.200406   2.420893
11  -0.253629   -0.627245   0.151471    0.151471    0.000000    0.000000
12  -0.820573   -0.212886   -0.566944   -0.415473   0.000000    0.000000
13  0.473439    2.532487    1.294012    0.000000    0.878539    0.385916
14  -1.395435   1.016338    -1.868875   0.000000    -1.868875   1.746346
15  -0.244269   -0.337820   1.151166    0.000000    1.151166    0.662592
16  -2.084977   -1.262249   -1.840708   0.000000    -1.840708   1.694103
17  0.666323    -1.696245   2.751300    0.000000    2.751300    3.784825
18  0.235207    -0.513903   -0.431115   -0.431115   0.000000    0.000000
19  1.386456    -0.149153   1.151249    0.000000    0.720134    0.259296
20  0.093456    -0.298154   -1.293000   0.000000    -1.293000   0.835925
21  0.690499    -1.687416   0.597043    0.000000    0.597043    0.178230
22  1.287530    -1.390260   0.597031    0.000000    0.597031    0.178223
23  1.828138    -0.288829   0.540608    0.000000    0.540608    0.146128
24  0.209666    -0.903385   -1.618472   0.000000    -1.618472   1.309727
25  -1.010678   0.615569    -1.220344   0.000000    -1.220344   0.744619
26  -1.799800   1.536332    -0.789122   0.000000    -0.789122   0.311357
27  0.611096    -1.033066   2.410896    0.000000    2.410896    2.906209
28  -0.532675   -0.091541   -1.143770   0.000000    -1.143770   0.654105
29  2.468137    -1.046117   3.000811    0.000000    3.000811    4.502435
```

Comment: provide the expected output

Comment: Can you put a `seed` for numpy, otherwise it is impossible to provide the same output and see what goes wrong because of the randomness of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted your `for` loop using a numpy array to hold the conditions and then `np.where` to replace the values according to your condition:

1. Define condition array

```
condition = np.abs(df.C.shift() + df["diff"]) > reset_level
```

2. Replace the values according to condition

```
df.iloc[:, 3] = np.where(condition, np.zeros((df.shape[0])), (df['C'].shift() + df['diff']))
df.iloc[:, 4] = np.where(~condition, np.zeros((df.shape[0])), (df['C'].shift() + df['diff']))

df.iloc[:, 5] = 0.5 * df['D'] * df['D']
```

Output:

```
           A         B      diff         C         D         E
0  -0.432513 -0.259526       NaN       NaN  0.000000  0.000000
1  -1.120872 -1.572850 -0.688360  0.000000       NaN       NaN
2  -0.917555 -2.251316  0.203317  0.203317  0.000000  0.000000
3  -1.869781 -1.284524 -0.952225  0.000000 -0.748908  0.280432
4  -2.041950 -0.091837 -0.172169 -0.172169  0.000000  0.000000
5  -0.142499  0.207746  1.899451  0.000000  1.727282  1.491751
6   1.432833  0.085211  1.575332  0.000000  1.575332  1.240835
7  -2.500191 -0.009907 -3.933025  0.000000 -3.933025  7.734341
8   0.154460 -1.859954  2.654651  0.000000  2.654651  3.523587
9  -0.565057 -0.516736 -0.719517  0.000000 -0.719517  0.258853
10  0.329845  0.127978  0.894902  0.000000  0.894902  0.400425
11 -0.920558  1.254617 -1.250402  0.000000 -1.250402  0.781753
12 -1.396913  0.262378 -0.476355 -0.476355  0.000000  0.000000
13  0.117336 -0.439932  1.514249  0.000000  1.037894  0.538612
14 -0.227066  2.565831 -0.344402 -0.344402  0.000000  0.000000
15  0.077750  0.195277  0.304816  0.304816  0.000000  0.000000
16  1.470611 -0.357213  1.392861  0.000000  1.697677  1.441053
17 -0.553844  0.339270 -2.024455  0.000000 -2.024455  2.049209
18 -0.259603  0.212839  0.294242  0.294242  0.000000  0.000000
19  0.605961  0.279599  0.865564  0.000000  1.159805  0.672574
20 -0.326706 -0.774350 -0.932667  0.000000 -0.932667  0.434934
21 -0.927601 -2.360751 -0.600895  0.000000 -0.600895  0.180537
22 -0.372085  0.986228  0.555516  0.000000  0.555516  0.154299
23 -0.687731 -2.966817 -0.315647 -0.315647  0.000000  0.000000
24 -0.041028 -0.328898  0.646703  0.000000  0.331057  0.054799
25  0.099489  0.275983  0.140517  0.140517  0.000000  0.000000
26  0.468274 -0.287097  0.368785  0.368785  0.000000  0.000000
27  0.497417 -0.588481  0.029143  0.029143  0.000000  0.000000
28  0.603178  2.243163  0.105761  0.105761  0.000000  0.000000
29 -0.643283 -1.051491 -1.246461  0.000000 -1.140700  0.650598
```

Is this what you were looking for, you didn't provide expected output.

> Documentation:
>
> - [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (but don't iterate over all rows - it will do the whole column at once for you):

```py
df["C_prev"] = df["C"].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 2), columns=list('AB'))
reset_level = 0.5
df['diff'] = df['A'].diff()
df['C'], df['D'], df['E'] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Then apply a function to each row:

```
def f(row):
    if abs(df.loc[row.name - 1, 'C'] + row['diff']) > reset_level:
        C = 0.0
        D = df.loc[row.name - 1, 'C'] + row['diff']
    else:
        C = df.loc[row.name - 1, 'C'] + row['diff']
        D = 0.0
    E = 0.5 * row['D'] * row['D'] 
    return(pd.Series([C, D, E]))

df.loc[1:, ['C', 'D', 'E']] = df[1:].apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks but problem is the values in 'C' are all initialized at 0 when you create history

Comment: @VolGuy Good catch, I had forgotten about that. See my updated answer (@SmileyProd's is very elegant too).